# R: Selecting multiple colums in is.na

Tags: r, multiple-columns, na

I would like to use the !is.na command to remove rows partially containing NAs:

```
table=data.frame(col1=c(1:2,NA,4,NA,4),col2=c(7:9,NA,NA,NA),col3=c(2:4,NA,NA,4),col4=c(1:6))

col1 col2 col3 col 4
1    7    2    1     
2    8    3    2 
NA   9    4    3
4    NA   NA   4
NA   NA   NA   5
4    NA   4    6
```

this should all happen INSIDE an lme-environment, something like:

```
lme(col1~ log(col2)+col3, random= ~ 1 |col4, data=table[(!is.na(table[c("col1","col2","col3","col4")])),], method="ML")
```

it won't work with this code - has anyone another suggestion?

Comment: @Roland I'd put that as answer really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `?lme` and pay special attention to the `na.action` parameter, which you could set to `na.omit` or `na.exclude`. However, if you want to compare models, it would be better to do that outside `lme`, e.g., `lme.dat <- na.omit(table)`. That way all models would use the same data.

Comment: thank you, I adapted your solution by creating a subset for the individual columns.

however, when using          stepAIC na.omit    or   na.exclude     won't work, only     is.na    will do

Comment: and please tell me how to mark code here in the comments-section ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `complete.cases` command on the subset of columns you want to check. For example:

```
df[complete.cases(df[,5:8]),]
```

This discards every row where in the selection is at least one `NA`.